# Using Firestore for Survey Data - everybody can write, a few can read

Tags: api, google-cloud-firestore, key

I'm setting up an online survey. This survey will be anonymous - to fill it all you need to have is the survey's URL. I want to store the survey answers in Firestore, and later run scripts that retrieve the data and generate reports.

I want to set it up so that everybody can write to it, but only specific accounts that have access to the project can read the data. I've set up the following rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow write;
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to create the script that reads the data, and I'm not sure - which API key should I use? Firestore automatically created a firebase-sdk-admin service account - should I use this account? There are also the Browser Key and Web client Key that were created automatically. Are those the ones to use?

What I would *really* want is to set up the script in a way that asks me for my Google Credentials (much like the gcloud sdk does it). That way there's no sensitive information in the script at all - if the script user logs in to Google with an account that has access to the database - it works. If it doesn't - it doesn't.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can either user [Firebase Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) which are basically like roles in Discord so or store UIDs of authorized users in Firestore or RTDB. Then you can write you security rules like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
    }
  }
}
```

Now only the users with "admin" claim set to true will be able to write to those documents. If you go with storing the user UIDs in a Firestore document then you can check if user's UID is present their as shown below:

```
allow write: get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;
```

Regarding the Service Account, you **should not** use them from frontend. They grant privileged access to your Firebase resources i.e. security rules are redundant. So you usually use them with the Firebase Admin SDK in a secure server env like Cloud functions. You can create a [Firebase Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) and then allow only whitelisted users to invoke it. That means if unauthenticated users or someone you haven't whitelisted won't be able to invoke it.

If you want to give access to your database to a teammate, then you can add members to your project from the Firebase Console. Let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: Users do not have user IDs, all access is anonymous. Reading should be limited to admins of the system, and is not done from the frontend.

Comment: @zmbq how are you authenticating users?

Comment: I am not. This is an anonymous survey, users are not authenticated.

Comment: @zmbq I mean for the people who can write to Firestore? You will need to add some sort of auth or give them access to the console.

Comment: Everybody can write to firestore. That's the whole point here. If you take the survey, you can write to firestore. You can't read anything from it, though, just write to it.

Comment: @zmbq sure I can help with it but can you please share a screenshot of how your database structure looks like? A sample document maybe?

Comment: The database is going to have one collection (/responses) with one document per response. The content of the document doesn't really matter, ordinary users cannot read these documents at all, just write them.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Since I want to let everybody write, and only read data from scripts run by admins and not users, I can set up the following access rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if false;
      allow write;
    }
  }
}
```

For reading, my scripts will authenticate as a service account (keeping the service account json file a secret), and will be able to read the data properly.